# MX record for transactional email

Tags: dns, transactional-email, sendinblue

I am interested in purchasing a domain, say `mydomain.net` 
My application, whose url I want to be `mydomain.net`, would send transactional email for authenticating new users. For this purpose I decided to choose `Sendinblue`. 
 
I want the sender of my transactional emails be `noreply@mydomain.net`,
thus I will add a new domain at sendinblue and call it `mydomain.net`. Then I will add a new sender at Sendinblue and call it `noreply@mydomain.net` 
Am I expected to add a MX record at my hosting provider (and also name registrar) to set the mail delivery destination towards Sendinblue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MX records are used to receive mails only. Since you will be sending from `Sendinblue` and you will not receive answers to `noreply@mydomain.net` you do not need to create MX record for this.